# Дискорд-бот на JS Работает только одна команда из трёх

Tags: javascript, java, бот, discord

У меня написан бот на Java Script, Работает только команда "clear" - удаление сообщений, команды "say" - повтор сообщения и "test" - отправка тестового сообщения не работают Код:

```
const config = require('./config.json'); // Подключаем файл с параметрами и информацией
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Подключаем библиотеку discord.js
const prefix = config.prefix; // «Вытаскиваем» префикс

// Команды //

function test(robot, mess, args) {
  mess.channel.send('Test!')
}

function say(robot, mess, args) {
  if (!mess.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return mess.channel.send("У  вас нет прав"); /* Если у исполнителя команды нету привилегии MANGAGE_MESSAGES, он не сможет её использовать */
    args = mess.content.split(' ');
    args.shift();
    args = args.join(' ');
    mess.delete().catch(); // Удаление сообщения пользователя после отправки 
    mess.channel.send(args)
  }
  
function clear(robot, mess) {
const arggs = mess.content.split(' ').slice(1); // Все аргументы за именем команды с префиксом
const amount = arggs.join(' '); // Количество сообщений, которые должны быть удалены
if (!amount) return mess.channel.send('Вы не указали, сколько сообщений нужно удалить!'); // Проверка, задан ли параметр количества
if (isNaN(amount)) return mess.channel.send('Это не число!'); // Проверка, является ли числом ввод пользователя 
if (amount > 100) return mess.channel.send('Вы не можете удалить 100 сообщений за раз'); // Проверка, является ли ввод пользователя числом больше 100
if (amount < 1) return mess.channel.send('Вы должны ввести число больше чем 1'); // Проверка, является ли ввод пользователя числом меньше 1
async function delete_messages() { // Объявление асинхронной функции
    await mess.channel.messages.fetch({
        limit: amount
    }).then(messages => {
        mess.channel.bulkDelete(messages)
        mess.channel.send(`Удалено ${amount} сообщений!`)
    })
};
delete_messages(); // Вызов асинхронной функции
}

// Список команд //

var comms_list = [{
  name: "test",
  out: test,
  about: "Тестовая команда"
}];

var comms_list = [{
  name: "say",
  out: say,
  about: "Повтор сообщения"
}];

var comms_list = [{
  name: "clear",
  out: clear,
  about: "удаление сообщений пользователей"
}];

// Name - название команды, на которую будет реагировать бот
// Out - название функции с командой
// About - описание команды 

module.exports.comms = comms_list
```

Comment: Возможно вам кто-то и поможет, если вы дадите больше деталей. Например какая команда работает, а какие - нет. И как вы определяете что они работают/не работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вас не смущяет такое

```
var comms_list = [{
  name: "test",
  out: test,
  about: "Тестовая команда"
}];

var comms_list = [{
  name: "say",
  out: say,
  about: "Повтор сообщения"
}];

var comms_list = [{
  name: "clear",
  out: clear,
  about: "удаление сообщений пользователей"
}];
```

объявление 3 переменных с одиннаковым именем ....

может всё же так поможет

```
var comms_list = [{
  name: "test",
  out: test,
  about: "Тестовая команда"
}];

comms_list.push({
  name: "say",
  out: say,
  about: "Повтор сообщения"
});

comms_list.push({
  name: "clear",
  out: clear,
  about: "удаление сообщений пользователей"
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает

Comment: @Дмитрий внимательнее конечно. Не торопитесь и спасибо.